# .env reload with django-environ on uwsgi

Tags: django, dotenv

I really need some punch.
I do have fully setup and running project. Django, nginx, supervisor, uwsgi - emperor with touch reload enabled.

```
 # {{ ansible_managed }}

[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown {{ deploy_user }}:{{ deploy_group }} /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '{{ uwsgi_path }}/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals'
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

uwsgi.ini

```
# {{ ansible_managed }}

[uwsgi]
project = {{ project_name }}
uid = {{ deploy_user }}
gid = {{ deploy_group }}
base = /home/%(uid)

chdir = %(base)/www/{{ project_url }}/%(project)
home = %(base)/.pyenv/versions/%(project)
module = config.wsgi
;logto = /tmp/uwsgi.log

master = true
processes = 10
harakiri = 30

socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(uid):%(gid)
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

touch-reload = {{ project_path }}/{{ project_name }}.touch

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
env = DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=True
;todo version for prod
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.{{ version }}
```

when I make changes and touch file, it reloads everything as should, project running perfectly.

But I do have an issue with .env file.

django settings.py

```
import environ
...
env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)
# reading .env file
env.read_env(str(ROOT_DIR.path('.env')))
```

If I change something in .env file and upload it to the server, touch wsgi file, it does not reflect changes in .env file. If I call manuall 'service uwsgi.project restart' it loads new file content.

The question: Do I missed something in config? How can I force uwsgi to reload .env file content when touch the file.

Thank you

Comment: what's the content of your  *.touch file?

Comment: No content, just file created with ansible file: state: touch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so the answer is not to use `django-environ`

> django-environ: ... strings from os.environ are loaded from a .env file and filled
>   in os.environ with setdefault method, to avoid to overwrite the real
>   environ.

and here is the trick, if your code already set some env variable, it won't be updated on uwsgi reload, to do so, you have to restart whole service -> this is no go with zero downtime deployment nor with touch-reload.

Using `python-dotenv` you are able to override this behaviour and update your envs on each reload, it works even with django dev server.

Happy coding guys!